# how to make duplicate value in datagridview cell

Tags: vb.net, datagridview, duplicates, cell

I want to make duplicate value in the data grid view column..
Let say when i enter a value in first cell(column) the second column automatically write the same value.

[image: my data Grid View]

just like my picture attached, when I enter(type) data at `Device ID`, the same data will be automatically type at the `FILE` cell.
Can somebody can help me to do this, I really really appreciate it. 
Thank You

Comment: [Enter the overused question in StackOverflow]: _What have you tried so far?_

Comment: The answer depends on the way you show data in `DataGridView`. What's `DataSource` of `DataGridView`?